# How to capture OnStateChange event for manually entered iframe for YouTube video

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I have need to be able to capture the onstatechange event for a youtube video that exists as a manually entered iframe (not built up via javascript) but unfortunately I can't figure out how to do it or if its even possible.  Looking at the YouTube docs there are plenty of examples of wiring up the event handler when you create the player via JS but I can't seem to find a way to do it for a pre-existing iframe.  My code is below:

```
<iframe id="video_player" enablejsapi="1" width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ANYVIDEO rel=0&start=0&end=71" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script>
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(playerId) {
    player = document.getElementById("video_player");
    player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "video_state_change");
}
function video_state_change(data){
    alert("STATE_CHANGE: " + data);
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWFObject to integrate your youtube player.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="video_player" width="650" height="400" data="//www.youtube.com/v/ANYVID?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></object>
```

This would allow you to use the JS API.

Next step is pretty simple. Add the following JavaScript snippet to your HTML file.

```
// Called automatically as soon as the player loads    
function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
    player = document.getElementById("video_player").get(0);
    player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "video_state_change");
}
```